# How loop through data of JSON arrays inside of arrays using Angular/TypeScript

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to call JSON objects within JSON objects but am unable to do so. When I attempt to, it outputs as [object Object].

I've attempted everything but I am new to angular and not sure how else to approach this. I've tried using foreach but it gives me constant errors. I've tried researching various methods but have not had any luck.

JSON File (students.json) - From here I want the values of coursedetails

```
[{
     "name": "Thomas Scott",
     "id": "5353553",
     "contact": "info@tom.ca",
     "courses": 
     [{
         "coursecode": "BFKG1232",
         "coursename": "User Design",
         "coursedetails":
         [{
            "date": "January 3rd 2018",
            "time": "3pm",
            "professor": "Josh Swede"
         }]
     },
     {
         "coursecode": "BJKRE4424",
         "coursename": "Integrated Design",
         "coursedetails":
         [{
            "date": "January 7th 2018",
            "time": "6pm",
            "professor": "Bill Timothy"
         }]
     }]
 }]
```

Typescript in the app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
studs: any = [];

selectedStud = '';
constructor( private getStud: GetStudentsService ) {}

  this.getStud.getStudents().subscribe(
  data => { this.studs = data; },
  err => { console.log('Error'); },
  () => { console.log('Completed'); }
  );} 

  showCour() {
    this.courBut = true;} 

    selectItem(istud) {
    this.selectedStud = istud; } 
}
```

show-courses.component.html how i am calling them in html. i can grab coursecode and coursename properly but coursedetails will not show.

```
<div>
    <strong>Courses</strong><br>
    <ul *ngFor="let lst of selStud.courses">
    <li>{{lst.coursecode}} - {{lst.coursename}}</li>
    <br>
    <li>{{lst.coursedetails}}</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

app.component.html (mainpage)

```
    <div style="padding:1em;" >
      <ul *ngFor='let istud of studs'> 
      <button (click)="selectItem(istud)">{{istud.name}}</button>
      <br> <br> <br>

      <button><a *ngIf="selectedStud" class="clickable"
        (click)="showCour($event)">{{cour}}</a></button>
      </ul><hr>
      <p>

      <app-show-student *ngIf="selectedStud" [selStud]="selectedStud">
      </app-show-student>
      </p>
      </div>

      <app-show-courses *ngIf="courBut" [selStud]="selectedStud">
        </app-show-courses>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Basically first I call the student first (thomas scott)
then once I do on click event, it will call the courses. I can call the coursecode and coursname without issue but once I call coursedetails, it only shows [object, Object].

Can anyone tell me how I would be able to access the coursedetails that are in the JSON file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As coursedetails is an array, you also need to iterate over it:

**show-courses.component.html**

```
<div>
    <strong>Courses</strong><br>
    <ul *ngFor="let lst of selStud.courses">
        <li>{{lst.coursecode}} - {{lst.coursename}}</li>
        <br>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let detail of lst.coursedetails">
            <li>{{ detail.date }}</li>
            <li>{{ detail.time }}</li>
            <li>{{ detail.professor }}</li>
        </ng-container>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Also if you are sure that you'll always get one object inside that array (not more than one), then you can also access that first object directly like this

```
<div>
    <strong>Courses</strong><br>
    <ul *ngFor="let lst of selStud.courses">
        <li>{{lst.coursecode}} - {{lst.coursename}}</li>
        <br>
        <li>{{ lst.coursedetails[0].date }}</li>
        <li>{{ lst.coursedetails[0].time }}</li>
        <li>{{ lst.coursedetails[0].professor }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a second loop inside the first one in order to access **coursedetails**

my solution would be something like this

```
    <div>
        <strong>Courses</strong><br>
        <ul *ngFor="let lst of selStud.courses">
            <li>{{lst.coursecode}} - {{lst.coursename}}</li>
            <br>
            <li *ngFor="let course_details of lst.coursedetails">{{course_details.professor}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```